# gdb: see unused struct typedef

Tags: c++, gdb

I am having trouble seeing all the typedefs of a struct I defined. In particular, if a typedef is not used, gdb does not show it when the type is printed. Here's an example:

```
struct D
{
  typedef double dtype;
  typedef int itype;
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
  D::dtype t;

  t = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run gdb, I then type `ptype D`, but I get only the following

```
(gdb) ptype D
type = struct D {
    typedef double dtype;
}
(gdb)
```

Is there a way to print all the typedefs even if they are not used?
Miscellaneous info:

1. I have `set print type typedefs on`
2. I compiled with debug symbols: `g++ -g -o test main.cpp`
3. gdb version is 7.10
4. gcc version is 5.3

Comment: Why is this tagged [С] in addition to [С++]? This appears to be a C++-specific question.

Comment: Well, the typedef keyword exists also in C, no?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot nest typedefs into structs in C. I.e. this very issue does not exist in C.

Comment: Yes.  This is not a valid C program

Comment: Ah, ok. I code mostly in C++ and did not now that. I'll take it down.

Comment: I think this is just an optimization that GCC is making. Since the second `typedef` is never used, there's no need to store information about it in the executable file.

Comment: Have you tried `-O0` to disable all optimizations?

Comment: -O0 should be the default, at least according to gcc webpage https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html. Anyways, I tried, and got the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC by default omits unused types from debug info.  If you really need this type to appear in the debug info, use `-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types`.  However, as the manual warns, this will bloat the resulting debug info.

Comment: YES! Thank you, that worked! And you're right, this should be an extreme solution. Point is, in the real code (not the example I posted) the second typedef SHOULD be used, but I can't access it from gdb, which makes me think it is not used. However, I wanted to check whether or not it was correct to start with.

Thanks!